# Why doesn't microsoft change the implementation of SetPixel() to an implementation that's faster?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, pixel

I have a question about the Bitmap class. If you want to set a lot of pixels on the bitmap, then you can use the `SetPixel` method, but it's very slow. There is a lot of documentation on how you can speed it up with the `LockBits` methodes etc, so i've created a method: `SetFastPixel`to speed it up a bit.

However, and I'm really confused by it: **Why doesn't microsoft change the implementation of SetPixel() to an implementation that's faster?** In other words, is there and advantage for using `SetPixel` instead of the `LockBits` method?

Comment: How sure are you that your implementation is faster?  The MS implementation is pretty much a direct call down to [GDI+ Flat API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533971%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm very sure. I've used the StopWatch class to measure both execution times. The `lockbits` method is like 5x faster in my case (redrawing a whole bitmap (265*265).

Comment: Could you link these "a lot of documentation on how you can speed it up with the LockBits methodes"?

Comment: http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/ http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-ii http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Comment: @Timo Are you sure your implementation has the same functionality as SetPixel, same parameters, and leaves the bitmap in the same state after each call?

Comment: @Timo I see no SetFastPixel function in any of those links.  Those lock the whole bitmap and change it all at once.  How are you implementing SetFastPixel that can lock/change/unlock faster than SetPixel?

Comment: @Timo, I think people are finding it difficult to envisage a 'SetFastPixel' being faster because lockbits is designed to allow acess to the image as an array of pixels. The speedup being the ability to write more than one pixel at a time. If you've implemented your 'SetFastPixel' with the same params, your loop is doing "Lock->write 1 pixel -> unlock->repeat" which is essentially what setpixel will do anyway, so you're not benefiting from using lockbits in any way

Comment: @Overflow, you're right!!! Oh my, I tried to simplify my question, but I've created a new problem with it. I can't believe I've asked that question. I'm also writing more then one pixel at a time. I'm sorry, but thanks for making it clear to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cases where `SetFastPixel` probably doesn't work:

- Monochrome devices (eight pixels packed into one byte)
- [Planar devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_(computer_graphics)) (16-color VGA cards have a strange memory layout and require hardware assistance)
- Indexed palette devices (`SetPixel` handles the RGB to palette index mapping)
- Printers (I've no idea how this would work via `LockBits`)
- Multi-monitor configurations where each card has a different pixel format

`SetPixel` is designed to handle all of the above, at the expense of being slow. If you're willing to sacrifice some of the above points, or if you're happy to handle them in your application, then you have the ability to draw images via `LockBits`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully buy this, The bitmap is stored in RAM when we're accessing via the bitmap class, and I would have imagined in a format nearer the bmp file formats than the potential output devices format.

Comment: Right: this is the difference between device-dependent and device-independent bitmaps. I'm not sure whether the `Bitmap` class in .NET assumes a DIB; the underlying `SetPixel` function in GDI pre-dates the existence of DIBs, so it supports anything that you can create an HDC on.

Comment: Either way, the logic to determine which memory format we're dealing with will be relatively fast (and constant) compared to the logic actually doing the work. This would equally apply to 'setfastpixel'. Lockbits speed advantage isn't a tradeoff with supported formats, its a tradeoff with the number of pixels you write in one go. If you write one pixel at a time with lockbits, they'd perform the same.

Comment: Assuming the `Bitmap` class only supports DIBs (and therefore doesn't need to go via the display driver), then I don't see why it couldn't support the SetFastPixel approach. In which case the answer to "Why doesn't microsoft change the implementation" is probably the same as many similar questions, i.e. a tradeoff between the number of feature requests and the resources to implement and test them all.

Answer (score 4):

To make an implementation that handles a specific bitmap format is easy, but there are a lot of different ways that an image can be stored in memory, so implementing a solution that handles all formats is a lot more complex.

A bitmap can for example be stored right side up or upside down in memory, with or without padding between lines, with many different number of bits per pixel.

Implementing that is just more work that it's worth to make the method a bit faster. Setting a single pixel at a time is inherently slow, so you shouldn't use that method anyway if you want speed.

Comment: I can't find a reference for this, but I remember reading that `SetPixel` is implemented as a 1x1 pixel `BitBlt` call in the kernel. This makes it guaranteed to work on all drivers, since it takes advantage of the plumbing that's already there for `BitBlt`, at the cost of being slow.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method to set a single pixel is inherently slow, no matter how you implement it, because, for each call, you must compute and check indexes, convert pixel format, etc.

Comment: But the method using `lockbits` is faster. And my question is, why didn't they implement the faster method instead of the slower.

Answer (score 1):

Direct3D was created just for this purpose.  Despite its name, it's still possible to do raw 2D pixel manipulation.  Generally put, you do it as:

- Create Direct3D context and device
- Create an offscreen surface
- Lock offscreen surface, render to its display buffer, unlock
- Copy offscreen buffer to device.

Yes, it is a lot more complicated than GDI, but it's coupled tightly to the hardware and drivers so that you control exactly where the rendering is occurring and how it's being displayed to the screen.  You'll never want to do any high performing graphics with GDI again.

Comment: Okay this seems interesting. I'm currently using the Bitmap class to do image transformations to small images (256*256, 512*512). However, it should also work for larger images. I'll look into this. Do you perhaps have an example online for this?

Comment: It just so happens I've written a blog post today about this with some sample code.  http://explodingcoder.com/blog/content/how-render-2d-directx-lets-try-rotozoomer

Answer (score 0):

They do not care because most people dont use it like that. C# is normally not used to render videos - and if you need stuff like that there are faster alternatives.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. They are the developers of the .net framework. And I can assume they think about the design and implementation of it. My question is, WHY would they choose for the slower implementation if they know how to do it faster.

Comment: Besides that, having a `SetFastPixel` implementation (or something similar) would be confusing for users of the API.

Comment: I'm not saying they should create a SetFastPixel method. I'm saying why are they not changing the SetPixel method's implementation to the SetFastPixel implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The classes in [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) are just a thin layer over the C++ classes used in [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Microsoft was not going expose a common interface (System.Drawing & GDI+) and have two classes which are supposed to act the same perform differently.